# Converting a dynamically added Dropdown control to a Dropkick control

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically added Dropdown controls to a webpage as the user scrolls down the page.
using Ajax.

I have no idea on how to convert the dynamically added DropDown Control to a [DRopKick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)(Jquery DropKick) control

All the dynamically added dropdowns have the same name

Dropkick is working as expected for controls that already exist on the page

Comment: How are you adding the dynamic controls?

Comment: using Ajax I am directly writing the HTML and assigning it to a <DIV>
tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the new controls, you need to call

```
$('select[name="<your-select-name>"]').dropkick();
```

Based on the updated comments, the following solution should work

```
$(txtVal).appendTo('#ContentPlaceHolder1_productList').filter('select[name="cbo_‌​products_listing"]').dropkick();
```